# NetBeans - Java EE server classpath is not correctly set up - server home directory is missing error

Tags: java, netbeans, classpath

I am getting an error when I try to build my project in NetBeans. I am using JBoss 5.1.0 server and have attached that to my project. The error is -

```
The following error occurred while executing this line:
.../myPath/build-impl.xml:176: The Java EE server classpath is not correctly set up -      server home directory is missing.
Either open the project in the IDE and assign the server or setup the server classpath manually.
For example like this:
ant -Dj2ee.server.home=<app_server_installation_directory>
```

I am using Mac OS X Lion.

Comment: there's a netbeans bug report that describes this problem, with a workaround http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=188751

Comment: that did not work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing a library. When I right clicked the project and went to libraries, it showed me library missing. I added the library and did a clean and build and the error disappeared

Answer (score 2):

Clean builds did not help me, either.  I took a look at project.properties and found that **j2ee.server.home** was not set anywhere, although **j2ee.platform.classpath** depends on it.

I do have Weblogic Server set up under /home (on a Linux machine).

So, I closed the project and added a line to project.properties:
j2ee.server.home=/home/blister/wls/wlserver

(where *wlserver* = the server name)

And reopened the project.  Presto, the app now builds.  It still doesn't know where the app server is, but at least I can built my jar and can worry about deploying it later.  (I tell it to build a *war* which deploys nicely to Weblogic.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using netBeans Ide, then right click on the project. click properties. in the properties menu select Run. in that the first text box is server. There select the server. with which u want to run the project. If the server details are not configured before. configure server details and try. it wil help you to solve the above problem.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

1. Right click on the Project -> Properties -> Run
2. And Change the server Setting from the current server to another sever and click OK.
3. Wait for any background scanning to finish.

Repeat the processes 1 to 3 again this time selecting the actual server you want to run the code on.

Then try Re-Running your application.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error. However despite adding servers in the Run section of the Properties window, repeatedly no servers showed as being available to add to the Project ( again within the Run section ). The solution to being able to see a server in this server list was to run Netbeans as an admin ( which I saw Rotunba referencing in this thread..It was then possible to add a server and the project built successfully..

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this, I added in the ANT properties field
"j2ee.server.home=http://localhost/"
tolls>options>java>Ant

this in linux netbeans

Answer (score -2):

It could also be as simple as not running your IDE i.e. netbeans as an administrator on your machine. I had the same problem. Wasted some time.